# No Encrypt button

Tags: nautilus, encryption, seahorse

I have noticed that for a while now there has been no button in Nautilus to encrypt something since either 11.10 or 11.04 but now I need to encrypt something and it hasn't reappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truecrypt is a good alternative. Please follow instructions [here.](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/11/encrypt-folders-partitions-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelotpart-i/)